# diagonal matrices kernels

Tags: linear-algebra

Reconsider A =(5,4,3;-1,0,-3;1,-2,1). We wish to find a basis which puts A in a nearly
diagonal form J = (4,1,0;0,4,0;0,0,2)

i. Select (your choice) a pair of non-zero vectors w ∈ E−2(A) and y ∈ Ker((A − 4I3))^2 \ Ker(A − 4I3). Compute the vector (A − 4I3)y based on your choice of y.

ii. Show that your choice of vectors {(A − 4I3)~y, ~y, ~w} in (i) forms a basis of R^3.
Hence,
create a 3 × 3 matrix P such that P^-1AP = J.

A and J are 3x3 matrix. E−2(A) is the eigenspace associated with eigenvalue -2. Please help with this question.

Comment: This is the way to put the matrix into _Jordan normal form_.  Did you start?  What's $E$?

Comment: Okay, the $E$ stands for eigenspace.  That makes sense.

Comment: Well it looks like you sort of have three kernels to compute.  Do you know how?  Once you do you'll be almost done.  Because the matrix $P$ will have columns equal to the three vectors.

Comment: no, i dont know how to compute kernels

Comment: "Kernel" is another word for "nullspace" (in this context). Do you know how to find the nullspace of a matrix? Anyway, I'd advise you to learn how to format math on this site, so you don't write horrible things like A-4I3~y that no one but you can understand. Start with the Help menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'll compute one of the kernels for you to get you started:  $E_{-2}(A)=\rm{ker}(A+2I_3)$.  Form the matrix and row reduce.  We get $\begin{pmatrix}7&4&3\\-1&2&-3\\1&-2&3\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&3\\0&18&-18\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&3\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.  Now that it's row-reduced, you can read off the kernel by "back-substitution".  You get $y=z$ and $x=2y-3z$.  So we can get a solution by setting say $y=z=1$, and $x=2(1)-3(1)=-1$. That is $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.  So that can be $w$.

Etc...

Comment: thankss..but i got the w alrdy...i dont know how to find y

Comment: oh darn... well, let's have a look.  you see, it's quite similar, because it's an element of one kernel that isn't in another kernel...

Comment: I thought you didn't know how to compute kernels.  How did you get $w$?

Comment: cause the question's part a asked to compute eigenspace associated with -2, so i got form there

Comment: got ya'.  But that shows how to compute a kernel, at least a little bit.